# « Voiture de courtoisie » peut-il signifier « voiture de remplacement » ?

Tags: usage, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, transports

Existe-t-il une différence entre les termes **voiture de courtoisie** et **voiture de remplacement**, ou sont-ils interchangeables ?

Par exemple, si un contrat avec un assureur dit qu’on a droit à une **voiture de remplacement** en cas d’accident, est-ce qu’on pourrait lui substituer le terme **voiture de courtoisie** ?

Answer (score 7):

Une voiture de courtoisie est généralement prêtée gratuitement par un garagiste durant la durée d'immobilisation d'un véhicule. La facture de la réparation est identique qu'il y ait eu un prêt ou non. La courtoisie est donc ici la pratique commerciale qui consiste à ne rien demander en échange, sauf de rendre le véhicule avec le même niveau de carburant que lors du prêt.

Une voiture de remplacement est d'un registre plus formel. L'utilisation de la voiture est susceptible d'être facturée directement (xx euros par jour) si elle est fournie par le garagiste ou forfaitairement et généralement fournie par une société de location de véhicules s'il s'agit d'un contrat d'assurance (prix fixe que l'on fasse appel au service ou non).

Answer (score 6):

Il me semble que l'appellation de *courtoisie* n'est qu'un vernis commercial, probablement jugé plus flatteur que le plus neutre *remplacement*, dans le contexte séducteur et manipulateur du langage publicitaire.

(Simple note : Suis-je le seul à voir un oxymore dans l'expression *voiture de courtoisie*?)

Comment: Ayant un doute sur la (systématique?) masculinité du terme *oxymore*, je vérifie vite fait sur le TLFi... pour trouver [ça](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oxymore). Inattendu.

Comment: C'est pas vraiment un oxymore, c'est juste que les deux termes ne collent pas ensemble.

Comment: Même résultat pour `oxymoron` dans TLFi. On trouve, par contre, les deux dans le Larousse.

Comment: Un occis mort, c'est un pléonasme.

Comment: Oui, et une plaie au nasme, ça fait mal. Bon, on arrête ? :-)

Comment: -1 pour le *séductif* : "... le contexte séducteur et manipulateur ..." par redondance de la finale phonique sonne plus fort. ET, je déconseillerais aux non francophones d'utiliser ce mot dans les traductions (il n'est même pas dans Wikipédia).

Comment: @RomainVALERI pour annuler le -1, ne vaudrait-il pas mieux corriger la réponse pour tout le monde?

Comment: @cl-r Après 6 ans de mûre réflexion, je te l'accorde entièrement. Point de hâtives décisions.

Answer (score 2):

On voit parfois l'inscription *véhicule de courtoisie* sur de telles voitures, je l'ai observé plusieurs fois. En termes de sens, la réponse est donc oui.

Maintenant, je doute que l'on puisse employer ces termes dans un contrat. Car si *remplacement* n'est pas ambigu, *courtoisie* pourrait l'être en termes de droit, sauf à ce qu'une définition de ce terme soit insérée dans le contrat.